# How to open JDialog form in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, jdialog

I've built class `JDialog form(diglog_promotion)` of Swing GUI, and a button. I want `JDialog` form showing when I click button so I've coded

```
dialog_promotion f = new dialog_promotion();                  
f.setVisible(true);
```

after I click button, it threw an error :

> NOT SUPPORTED YET

and I tried to use it with eclipe it works
what was I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
 Inside of your method Actionperformed for any particular case you want call JoptionPane.showMessageDialog(,); with the message you want. I have tried this in netbeans it works.
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
 ...
 ...
 if(saveisclicked)
{
  System.out.println("Please Fill user name");
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter  User Name field");

}
...
...
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: I dont mean JOptionPane I mean JDialog form class